# Convert Columns into rows only using select statement and where clause

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have a table like this

---

**Name**   **Preference_1**   **Preference_2**   **Preference_3**

**John          India             UK             USA**

Output should be like this

---

**Name**        **Preference_No**    **Location**

**John                 1               India**

**John                2             UK**

**John             3             US**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: I didn't try anything.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using `union` or `union all` like this:

```
select Name, '1' AS Preference_No, Preference_1 AS Location from your_table union
select Name, '2' AS Preference_No, Preference_2 AS Location from your_table union
select Name, '3' AS Preference_No, Preference_3 AS Location from your_table union
order by Name
```

**Note**: you can use `union all` not `union` to get all records otherwise what is repeated, but in your case you don't need to use `union all` because you are select static different values As Preference_No, so there is no records will repeated.

Comment: It's okay. But i need it by using only SELECT statement and WHERE clause without using UNION/UNION ALL.

Comment: i am fine with the code, but my requirement is like that.Could you please provide me the solution with my requirement.